# use sfinae to test namespace members existence

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, sfinae

I was trying to figure out if it is possible to use sfinae to test **namespace** member existence.
Google is rather silent about it. I've tried the following code, but it fails.

```
namespace xyz{
 struct abc{};
}

struct abc{};

struct test_xyz{ 
 typedef char yes;
 typedef struct{ char a[2]; } no;

 template <class C> static yes test(xyz::C = xyz::C()); //lets assume it has default constructor
 template <class C> static no test(...);

 const bool has_abc = sizeof(test_xyz::test<abc>()) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Any idea why?

Regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that won't work. There is also no way to use SFINAE in such a way (this was last discussed on usenet for a compatibility test against some C++0x component). The C inside `xyz::C` is not related to the template parameter at all.

Remember that templates are not just macros. The parameter `C` denotes not just a piece of text, but a semantical entity. In this case it is a type. It's bound already to the meaning it has as an argument. That is, if your class had a member of name `abc`, the meaning of the parameter still would not change.

If all you want is to use some struct `xyz::abc` if it exists, and `others::abc` otherwise, you can do some tricks to get there, but I'm not aware of a way that does it without touching `xyz`

```
namespace others {
  struct abc{};
}

namespace fallbacks {
  using others::abc;
}

namespace xyz {
  using namespace fallbacks;
}
```

Now if you say `xyz::abc` and `xyz` contains a member declared so, it will refer to that member (that member will hide the one in `fallbacks`. However if it doesn't contain that member, then the using directive's name will be found and refer to `fallbacks::abc`.