# Detect the existence of types

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae

[SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sfinae) allows us to detect if a type has certain data members or member functions. Can it also be used to detect if a type exists at all? Background: I want to know whether `<vector>` was included or not.

Comment: You want code that compiles whether `<vector>` was included or not, but does different things? That's evil, especially considering that it's up to the implementation how standard headers mutually include each other.

Comment: This suggests no, but I'm not at all good with SFINAE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600244/use-sfinae-to-test-namespace-members-existence/3600286#3600286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do, although I've only managed to make it work in C++0x.

```
struct no_type {};
struct is_vector_included {
    template<typename U> static decltype(std::vector<U>::iterator()) func( U* );
    template<typename U> static no_type func( ... );
    static const bool value = !std::is_same<no_type, decltype(func<int>(nullptr))>::value;
};
```

The structure is very curious and although there should be certain obvious simplifications, they don't work. More importantly, why don't you just `#include <vector>` to be certain?

Comment: Unfortunately, my "target audience" does not have a C++0x compiler. What is `no_type`?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Sorry- it's an empty struct. The idea is that there's no way that any other type could possibly be no_type, so whatever type I end up finding through decltype, if the substitution succeeded, it's certainly not no_type. Edit: Still curious as to why you don't just #include it.

Comment: @Dead: Simply including it is probably the easiest/cleanest way. Still curious if this is possible, though :)

Comment: @UncleBens: I made it work on MSVC10. It breaks at the drop of a hat, though, so if you had something really similar but not quite, then it won't work.

Comment: Could it be that MSVC compiles it because it (still) doesn't implement two-phase compilation of templates? - If vector is not included, it would fail for any U. If the error doesn't depend on U, would it be a **substitution** failure?

Answer (score 0):

I have one problem with the question:

If `<vector>` was not included, then how can you test whether a type has been introduced in the translation unit without knowing about it ?

You are effectively asking the compiler to test if `vector` exists, but how can you ask that without declaring `vector` first and foremost ?

I don't see how any solution could possibly work and be standard compliant, but I am no standardista so there might be a caveat I am not aware of.

Comment: the OP wants to know if vector was included or not in the first place

Comment: @Chusbad: and I understand that, but C++ does not allow to query for the presence (or absence) of a symbol as far as I know, since to USE a symbol (even in a simple `is_same` query) you need it to be DECLARED. How would `vector` be declared without `<vector>` be included ?