# Specializing template function for classes in different namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
class A{}
class B{}

namespace Other{

    class C {}
    class D {}

}

template<typename T> T func() {}
template<typename T> T func <Other::T>() {}
```

Why is it not possible to have specialized version for functions dependant on types in different namespaces? So basically what I want to have is a func version for all types in Other and another version for any other type. 
I'm new to TMP programming so sorry if the question seems trivial to some :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use sfinae to test namespace members existence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600244/use-sfinae-to-test-namespace-members-existence)

Comment: What did you try to compile? What error did you get?

Comment: I didn't really understand the solution in the question supposed to be duplicate!
@underscore_d The compiler thinks that T is actually a class inside Other namespace so It complains that T does not exist in Other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it not possible to have specialized version for functions dependant on types in different namespaces?

Because there exists no syntax in C++ to represent such specialization.

Your next question might be *why* such thing does not exist. I'm not Stroustrup, nor the committee nor even a member of the committee, so I can only guess. My guess is that such thing wasn't originally ever considered, but if it was, then it was simply considered to be a bad design decision.

It's also not trivial to specify how such specialization should behave in some situations. Consider following example:

```
namespace One{
    class C;
}

namespace Other{
    using One::C;
}
```

Which specialization should `Other::C` use? Whatever you decide, it's going to be confusing one way or the other.